# Is my AOL Mail account lost if the alternative mail is inaccessible?

Tags: account-recovery, aol-mail

I want to change the password of my `aol.de` account. I set up an alternative e-mail which is no longer accessible for me. Any tries to change the password end up with a form (and no alternative) offering to send a recovery link to that inaccessible mail.

If I lost my password and the alternative mail account is inaccessible (I set it up > 5 years ago and never bothered with it) I can forget about my AOL account.

That can't be true, can it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as it was true before, but meanwhile I was asked to enter another alternative mail address which allowed be to change the security question and then the password.